# How to store higher order function data in list in haskell?

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I'm trying to store function's result data in list but don't know how to define in the code.

I think the problem is 10th line.

```
| tst x == True  = [x,xs..]
```

How could I define list where I will store the result data of tst x?

So, the expected output is below.

```
Main> two_sear evn [2,4,5,8]
[2,4,8]
Main> two_sear big [101]
[101]
```

My current approach:

```
evn :: Int -> Bool
evn x = mod x 2 == 0

big :: Int -> Bool
big x = x > 100

two_sear::(Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Int]
two_sear tst [] = []
two_sear tst (x:xs)
    | tst x == True  = [x,xs..]
    | otherwise = two_sear tst xs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a [**`filter :: (a -> Bool) -> a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:filter) here. So instead of using your own `two_sear`, you can use filter instead.

For example:

```
Prelude> filter evn [2,4,5,8]
[2,4,8]
Prelude> filter big [101]
[101]
```

You can implement `filter` yourself through recursion:

```
filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p = go
    where go [] = []
          go (x:xs) | p x = x : go xs
                    | otherwise = go xs
```

We thus construct a list with `(x : go xs)`, or less verbose `x : go xs`. This is a "cons" with `x` the head of the list, and we recurse with `go xs` on the remaining items of the list.

The `go` function can be implemented as a `foldr` with:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

filter' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filter' p = foldr ((bool id . (:)) <*> p) []
```

The `Prelude` already has an implementation for [**`even :: Integral i => i -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:even) and you can define `big` as:

```
big :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> Bool
big = (<) 100
```

or:

```
big :: (Num n, Ord n) => n -> Bool
big = (100 <)
```

Comment: You're right but I should use only limited technique like what I wrote above. Could I solve them using guard?

Comment: @Hume: that is done in the implementation of `filter'`. Note that you do not need a guard, you can use a `Bool` catamoprhism.

Comment: Really appreciate for your reply. And have 2 questions. 1) why put the ' sign after filter? you didn't use is in "Prelude> filter evn [2,4,5,8]     2)what is the 'p' and 'go'? are these just name or keyword of Haskell?

Comment: @Hume: (1) because that would clash with the `filter` in the prelude, (2) `p` is the predicate to be satisfied for an item to be in the result; `go` is a "helper" function, such that we do not need to pass `p` from one recursive call to the next one.

Comment: So, it means they're not keyword. I can replace them to other words like p to y, and go to goooo. right?

Comment: @Hume: indeed, there is nothing special about `p` and `go`, but often people use these names, so it is more a "convention".

Answer (score 1):

Just in addition to the already good answer here. Functions in Haskell are like any other value, and also your current functions can be curried (indeed every function in Haskell is curried). Said that, here an example:

```
fs = [(+), (*), (-), (div)]
ints = [(2,4), (5,3), (6,2), (9,3)]

applyFs :: [a -> b -> c] -> [(a, b)] -> [c]
applyFs fs ns = zipWith (($) . uncurry) fs ns

=> [6,15,4,3]
```

As you can see, `fs` is a list a function, completely valid